# selecting keras regression model for 3 input and 1 output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

[image]

This my excel data scatter plot. I have 3 input and 1 output for my neural network model, totally 4 columns in excel. And 200 rows. Data is standart normalized.

[image]

So I have a keras model as following:

```
def create_model():
    ann_model = Sequential()
    ann_model.add(Dense(120, input_dim=3, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='tanh'))
    ann_model.add(Dense(60, activation='tanh'))
    ann_model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    return ann_model

original_inputs = read_inputs(r'train_cd.xlsx')
original_outputs = read_outputs(r'train_cd.xlsx')

model = create_model()

sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'accuracy'])

model.fit(original_inputs, original_outputs, batch_size=10, epochs=1800, verbose=False, shuffle=False)

test_result = model.predict(original_inputs)

# ----------Plot---------------------------------------------
plt.plot(original_outputs, label="y-original")
plt.plot(test_result, label="y-predicted")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
# -----------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

But this training result is not close to  %100 accuracy. How can I change the model hidden layer nodes or else? I want to get high accuracy close to 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to increase your accuracy, you can try differents things :

- Add more layer and play with their number of neurons
  -> With more layers and more neurons, the model can learn higher level patterns
- Print the model loss and accuracy history and see what the curves looks like (increase/decrease fast/slow, if you cap or maybe the model haven't finished to learn -> more epochs, etc)
- Play with the batchsize, change your optimizer, try differents activation functions

I hope that can help you

Comment: model history has 3 keys `['loss', 'mean_squared_error', 'acc']` and acc array has same values (0.12299465304389995)

Comment: But this is a time series data. Does it matter? Should I modify my code?